# How to destroy session in symfony 2.6?

Tags: symfony, session

I tried doing this:

```
$session->remove();
```

Also this:

```
$session->clear();
```

But it gives following error:

> Call to a member function clear() on a non-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> invalidate()
>
> Clears all session data and regenerates session ID. Do not use session_destroy().

This actually does what you want.

Source & more info:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Also such things are easy to check by simply review the source.

For this case you should check `Session` or `SessionInterface` source:

http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/SessionInterface.html

http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html

Edit.

Of course this method belongs to `Session` class so you have to access `Session` object first in your controller.

So we go to:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-the-session

and we see how to do that:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $session->invalidate(); //here we can now clear the session.
}
```

Comment: following error occurred

Attempted to call function "invalidate" from namespace "Home\HomeBundle\Controller

Comment: This is a method of `Session` object, not `Controller`. First you have to access `Session` object. See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks it solved my problem :) one more queastion...right now i'm doing this to start session in Action 

$session = new Session();
$this->session->start();

i want to write this $session = new Session(); in constructor and use it in all actions of controller. how can i do this, i cant find its syntax anywhere.

Comment: I think you should use built-in session management http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session Then you can access your session from every action in any controller.